# comment SQL query with variables in python

Tags: sql, python-3.x, google-bigquery

I'm working with Cloud Function. I have the following query working correctly:

```
# this is working
q = """ SELECT col1, col2
        FROM `my_table` 
        WHERE col1 = {} AND col2 = '{}'""".format(var1, var2)
```

however when trying to add a comment I have a `Keyerror`:

```
# this is not working
q = """ /* "{'query': 'some_name' */ 
        SELECT col1, col2
        FROM `my_table` 
        WHERE col1 = {} AND col2 = '{}'""".format(var1, var2)
```

The query is working with the comment if I'm removing the variables:

```
# this is working
q = """ /* "{'query': 'some_name' */ 
        SELECT col1, col2
        FROM `my_table` """
```

I'm using the following function to run my query:

```
def run_query(q):
    client = bigquery.Client()
    df_result = client.query(q).to_dataframe()
    return df_result
```

Why do I get this error? How should I comment in this context?

Comment: It seems you need to escape a curly brace in your comment by adding one more curly brace like this : `/* "{{'query': 'some_name' */ `

Comment: yes working and I understand why! thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72231791/comment-sql-query-with-variables-in-python#comment127618801_72231791) by @Jaytiger:

> you need to escape a curly brace in your comment by adding one more curly brace like this :
>
> ```py
> /* "{{'query': 'some_name' */
> ```